# Handling logging over data stream

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, logging, stream, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an EC2 instance that has a datastream that uses an event emitter to process data. E.g.

```
stream.on('new event', function doSomething(event){ do more stuff...})
```

This datastream has potentially tens of thousands of events per second, and I would like to log the processing of these events in an efficient manner. In other words, I'm reluctant to send out a log entry each time a new event comes in.

Hence, I figured I'd send logs in batch. E.g.

```
let logArray = [];
function sendToLogs(logs) {\** send stuff *\}

stream.on('new event', function doSomething(event){ 
  \\do some stuff

  logArray.push({newLog: event})
  if (logArray.length >= 500) {
     sendToLogs(logArray)
     logArray = [];
  }
})
```

However, I'm afraid that with so many events coming in simultaneously, that the above code could lead to erratic behavior. I've seen this in local logging: the length of this array jumps around pretty dramatically and can have the same value for different events simultaneously.

Furthermore, using cloudwatch logs requires me to pass 'sequenceTokens' between different calls to the logging function. If two events trigger the logging condition at the same time, things could get weird. (This problem would exist even if I logged each event separately.)

How should I handle logging over this kind of data stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate out the logging into one or more separate processes.  Your main application would put logging messages on an SQS queue using a "fire and forget" type of logic.  Your logging application would then read the queue and write to the log of your choice.  The advantage is that bursts of activity would be absorbed by the queue.  There are no direct limits in the length of a queue so it should be able to handled.  In effect you're no longer queuing messages, SQS is.

Additionally, if the queue grows more than you'd like you could have multiple logging applications to handle the load.

The downsides are:

1. You need to write this separate process to handle the logging to CloudWatch or where ever.
2. Your logs will not be real time.  There will be at least some latency between when your main application logs and when the log message is put into CloudWatch.  With additional logging processes you should be close but it isn't a guarantee.

Comment: SQS could definitely work. Lambda functions would be another option if a closer to real time behavior is needed. If the fire and forget process just delegates to lambda you'd wind up with a "fan out" pattern where lambda would dynamically scale to the number of logging processes required.